# Clearing list view without deleting columns in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I need help regarding list view. I'm trying to remove the records in my list view but when I try to use lvRecords.Clear() it also removes the columns that I need. I just need to clear the records not the columns. :(

Comment: The Clear method on a listview does exactly that.

Use lvRecords.Items.Clear() instead.

Just found out the answer for my own question. lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx), the `ListView.Clear` method

> Removes all items **and columns** from the control.

To clear just the items, you need to call the `Clear` method on the `Items` property.  Try this instead:

```
lvRecords.Items.Clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the column setup in a separate method and then once you clear it call the setup method